# Express 401 redirect is not happening automatically

Tags: node.js, redirect, express

Encountering a situation where I redirect users with a 401 when they're not authorized to access a page. I have this in one of my routes:

```
 res.redirect(401, '/login');
```

Seems simple enough, but the app loiters and doesn't redirect the user to `/login`. It just sits on a page similar to this:

```
 Unauthorized. Redirecting to /login
```

Headers look fine too:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: Express
Location: /login
Vary: Accept
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 63
set-cookie: connect.sid=stuff; Path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Sun, 20 Nov 2016 02:20:07 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

The weird thing is that if I omit the status, the redirect happens normally:

```
 res.redirect('/login'); // doesn't hang on page, redirect occurs immediately
```

I was under the impression that redirection would be automatic, but maybe not? Any insight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

401 is not a redirect status. Just use a regular (303) redirect instead – [401 is invalid if you’re not sending a `WWW-Authenticate` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) anyway.

Comment: Makes sense! +1 for the speedy response